# Live Vid Streaming - Unacceptable Delay

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, wowza

I'm doing a live vid streaming application where "almost" realtime user interaction is required. Basically it will be something like a live Q&A where audience get to ask question and the live broadcaster will have to answer the question almost immediately - there is a strict requirement where delay more than 7 seconds is unacceptable.

I'm currently using OBS as the broadcaster software and I have tried DaCast and Wowza Cloud streaming service. Both of them ingest RTMP and output in HLS and after trans-coding typically I'd get around 30 - 45 seconds delay which is unacceptable.

Is there any other alternative that I could consider? I'm looking for a solution where it takes RTMP as the ingestion protocol and outputs also as RTMP. Research indicates that this will make the delay significantly lower.

Thanks

Comment: any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Wowza Streaming Engine server instead of the Cloud product, as this outputs an RTMP stream. HLS streams, since it is an HTTP streaming protocol, are inherently more latent than an RTMP stream. This means that you will need an RTMP player.